# Dynamic Difficulty Adjustment

Tags: dynamic-difficulty

Isn't there any algorithms for Dynamic Difficulty Adjustment? like a universal algorithm. Or is it made depending on the game that it will be implemented to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a universal algorithm for dynamic difficulty adjustments?

No, there is not.

> Or is it made depending on the game that it will be implemented to?

That's it!

Chess and Mario Kart are not played the same, the same rules do not apply, etc. There is no way to have the same algorithm for dynamic difficulty for both games.

Comment: As I thought. so it does really depend of what type of game and what adjustment would you want the algorithm to do. Thanks for clarifying. Been searching the internet for possible algorithms for quite a while.

Comment: @MazoKisto I know someone who wrote a [paper](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~jtremb59/Dynamic%20Difficulty.html) on that, if it can inspire your designs.